# Avoid recreating of Fragment by press back arrow using Navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments

I saw similar questions on SO, but I could not find an answer.

If I receive data from the server (list of movies) and display it on the screen, then scroll down and click on some movie to watch the info, then I press the back arrow and the list is updated again, that is, the fragment is recreated and makes a request to the server on a new one.How can I avoid it so that when I press the back arrow, I continue to scroll down from the element on which I stopped. I use Navigation component and I use MVVM patter and I use Paging V3 library.

This is my ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val moviePagingSource: MoviePagingSource
) : ViewModel() {

     fun fetchPopularMoviesWithDetails(): Flow<PagingData<PopularMovieWithDetailsModel>>{

             return Pager(config = PagingConfig(
                 pageSize = 20,
                 enablePlaceholders = false
             ),
                 pagingSourceFactory = { moviePagingSource }
             ).flow
         }

}
```

This is my MovieListFragmetn method where I call data from ViewModel

```
 private fun setupMoviesList() {

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.fetchPopularMoviesWithDetails().collectLatest {
                moviesAdapter.submitData(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my MovieListFragmetn method where I navigate to DetailsMovieFragmetn

```
  private fun openMovieDetailsScreen() {
        moviesAdapter.onClickItem(object : MovieAdapter.OnclickMovieItemListener {
            override fun getMovieModel(movieWithDetailsModel: PopularMovieWithDetailsModel) {
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putKSerializable("movieObject", movieWithDetailsModel)
                findNavController().navigate(
                    R.id.action_homeFragment_to_movieDetailsFragment,
                    bundle
                )
            }

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the Paging documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data#pagingdata-stream):

> The `cachedIn()` operator makes the data stream shareable and caches the loaded data with the provided `CoroutineScope`.

But you aren't using `cachedIn()`, which is why your data is not being cached and saved (which is what makes it instantly available when you return to that fragment, without fetching from the source again).

You should follow the example in the docs:

```
val popularMoviesWithDetails: Flow<PagingData<PopularMovieWithDetailsModel>> =
    Pager(config = PagingConfig(
        pageSize = 20,
        enablePlaceholders = false
    ),
        pagingSourceFactory = { moviePagingSource }
    ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Comment: I added cachedIn(viewModelScope) but nothing was changed

Comment: Did you change it to be a `val` and not return a brand new Flow each time? You can't use a method for this.

Comment: You are right. My mistake was every time it was return brand new result

Answer (score 0):

I changed my ViewModel with a help of @ianhanniballake and it works corectly now

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val moviePagingSource: MoviePagingSource
) : ViewModel() {

    private var lastFetchedMovieResult: Flow<PagingData<PopularMovieWithDetailsModel>>? = null

    fun fetchPopularMoviesWithDetails(): Flow<PagingData<PopularMovieWithDetailsModel>> {

        val lastMovieResult = lastFetchedMovieResult
        if (lastMovieResult != null) return lastMovieResult

        val newFetchedMovieResult = Pager(config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 20,
            enablePlaceholders = false
        ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { moviePagingSource }
        ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

        lastFetchedMovieResult = newFetchedMovieResult

        return newFetchedMovieResult
    }

}
```